# In what 'certain limted situations' would Java EE6 require bean.xml file to NOT be empty?

Tags: jakarta-ee, javabeans, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

This question is in reference to this [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html); according to the doc the beans.xml file can be empty expect that "it has content only in certain limited situations." In what situations is the bean.xml file used to configure java beans in EE 6? Does this apply to Java EE 7? What does a 'configured' beans.xml file contain (SCCE please)?

Comment: One situation, when you use the [`@Alternative`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv002.htm) annotation (though I specifically do not know, if this can optionally be done in other ways round).

Answer (score 2):

One use is when configuring [Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/interceptors.html#_enabling_interceptors) (though this somewhat outdated with CDI 1.1).

> By default, all interceptors are disabled. We need to enable our interceptor. We can do it using beans.xml descriptor of a bean archive. However, this activation only applies to the beans in that archive. From CDI 1.1 onwards the interceptor can be enabled for the whole application using @Priority annotation.

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">
  <interceptors>
    <class>org.mycompany.myapp.TransactionInterceptor</class>
  </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Another one is [Decorators](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/decorators.html#_enabling_decorators), the use of beans.xml here is roughly the same as with interceptors.

The last use is [Alternatives](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#alternatives) (as mentioned by Tiny in the comments) or [Alternative stereotypes](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_alternative_stereotypes).

Comment: Could you add some SCCE's to example? Like the beans file and they the POJOs being referenced?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by SCCE's? Some examples are in the docs I linked like the bean.xml contents and some basic pojo examples. And also there is a beans.xml example in my answer?